# I want to count how many teachers are available at certain days

Tags: php

So for my website you can reserve certain spots and machines, but for the machines there need to be teachers available. So i need something that can count whenever a teacher is available. I don't really know what to add for this but what i do have is a system that can see if the teacher days are empty or not and if they are not empty it will say that a teacher is available. Even though it is really messy i'm still going to include it because it can probably be improved.

Also if you have questions if you don't really understand what i want, just ask, this is my first time asking here and i don't know how to ask a good question. Thanks

```
$show = new Teacher();
$works = $show->selectWork();

foreach ($works as $work) {

echo '<b>Teacher: </b>'.$work["teacherFirstName"],"&nbsp;".$work["teacherLastName"] .'<br>';
echo '<b>Days available: </b><br>';

echo '<b>Monday: </b>';
if(!empty($work["workMonday"])) {

echo $work["workMonday"];;
$work["workMonday"] = 'Monday';
} else{
echo 'not available';
}
echo '<br>';

echo '<b>Tuesday: </b>';
if(!empty($work["workTuesday"])) {

echo $work["workTuesday"];
$work["workTuesday"] = 'Tuesday';
} else{
echo 'not available';
}
echo '<br>';

echo '<b>Wednesday: </b>';
if(!empty($work["workWednesday"])) {

echo $work["workWednesday"];;
$work["workWednesday"] = 'Wednesday';
} else{
echo 'not available';
}
echo '<br>';

echo '<b>Thursday: </b>';
if(!empty($work["workThursday"])) {

echo $work["workThursday"];;
$work["workThursday"] = 'Thursday';
} else{
echo 'not available';
}
echo '<br>';

echo '<b>Friday: </b>';
if(!empty($work["workFriday"])) {

echo $work["workFriday"];;
$work["workFriday"] = 'Friday';
} else{
echo 'not available';
}
echo '<br>';


if(isset($work["workMonday"]) && ($work["workTuesday"]) && ($work["workWednesday"]) && ($work["workThursday"]) && ($work["workFriday"])) {
$timestamp = strtotime($_POST['reserveDate']);
$day = date('l', $timestamp);
echo '<b>' . $day . '</b><br>';

if ($day === $work["workMonday"] || $day === $work["workTuesday"] || $day === $work["workWednesday"] || $day === $work["workThursday"] || $day === $work["workFriday"]) {
                        echo 'someone is availabe';
                    } else {
                        echo 'no one is available';
                    }
                }


            }
```

Again, if there are any questions about my code or my question, be free to ask, i really need help and searching stuff up for this i don't get anything because of how specific it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$totalInMonday = 0;
foreach ($works as $work) {

 echo '<b>Teacher:
 </b>'.$work["teacherFirstName"],"&nbsp;".$work["teacherLastName"] .'<br>';
  echo '<b>Days available: </b><br>';

  echo '<b>Monday: </b>';
  if(!empty($work["workMonday"])) {
    ++$totalInMonday;
    echo $work["workMonday"];;
    $work["workMonday"] = 'Monday';
  } else{
    echo 'not available';
  }
}
echo $totalInMonday;
```

you can do this for all days and it'll increase if someone is available at that particular day, and the results will be stored in all 7 variables like `echo $totalInMonday` and so on,
I hope it'll help

Comment: Thank you so much, i was trying something with that but nothing was working. This works for me now, again thank you^^